# Convert existing html.erb to Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have a rails project, the views only consist with HTML.ERB files, my client wants to convert ERB to HAML. I have too many views file. It's taking a huge amount of time to convert file by file. So that any simply way I can convert HTML to haml? I installed haml plugin under my project.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There you go: http://html2haml.heroku.com/

EDIT: Moved to https://html2haml.herokuapp.com/

Comment: if I have html image tag <img src="abc.gif/> html2haml converts it to %img{:src => "abc.gif"} Is there a way to convert it to =image_tag "abc.gif" to use rails helpers?

Comment: This is not a 'bad' answer, but it should not be accepted as the best answer. The command line tool (below) is better.

Comment: Please read the post, he said he didn't want to convert each individual file.

Answer (score 103):

You can use from the command line **html2haml**

```
html2haml your_erb_file new_haml_file
```

If you want to convert all your files in one go, look at this article : http://shifteleven.com/articles/2008/06/08/converting-erb-to-haml-snippet

Comment: According to the [latest html2haml source code](https://github.com/haml/html2haml), html2haml "is in the process of being extracted from the haml gem."

Comment: now a [separate gem](https://github.com/haml/html2haml). looks like the current build isn't passing too.

Comment: I'm not too sure what the implications of the above two comments are supposed to be. I decided to give the command line `html2haml` a shot and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 17):

http://www.htmltohaml.com

A more user-friendly alternative to the selected answer.

Comment: User-friendly for small conversions, but a giant pain for doing a full app...

Answer (score 14):

David Leung provides [this gem](https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml) on github that installs two rake tasks.

With erb2haml, you can easily convert an entire project from erb to haml with either `rake haml:convert_erbs` or `rake haml:replace_erbs`.

Answer (score 14):

On the [haml-rails git page](https://github.com/indirect/haml-rails#converting-all-erb-views-to-haml-format), it provides the cli command to do convert all erb to haml right in your project.

add `gem "haml-rails"` to your Gemfile

run: `rake haml:erb2haml`

Comment: So easy, and WAY better than pulling in another gem IMO.

Answer (score 10):

**very simple**

in your `Gemfile` add

```
gem "erb2haml", :group => :development
```

then run `bundle install`

for Converting `*.erb` to `*.haml` keeping original files do:

```
rake haml:convert_erbs
```

for Converting `*.erb` to `*.haml` replacing original files do:

```
rake haml:replace_erbs
```

it'll search all the `erb` files in project and convert to `haml`.

**For shorthand: use on-line converter**

http://www.htmltohaml.com

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: html2haml does work as advertised, however you must use version obtained from the current master branch of the [haml github repoistory.](http://github.com/nex3/haml.git)

The version of html2haml included with the haml gem currently available from rubygems is no good. This is the version you will get if you were to do `gem install haml` right now. Using the version supplied with the gem will result in invalid haml, as it cannot process ruby properly.

Comment: Just wanted to add that as of now (2011/7/21), the haml gem's html2haml works.  However, you do have to `gem install hpricot` and `gem install ruby_parser` on top of haml.  If you try to do an erb->haml conversion, it'll prompt you to install these gems.

Answer (score 1):

html2haml is now in the html2haml gem, so you can use:

```
$ gem install html2haml
$ html2haml path/to/yourfile.html path/to/yourfile.haml
```

Comment: the application-wide answer is what is needed, not individual files. no one wants to type out individual files. it's only one step above doing it manually. an application-wide task will handle individual files.

Answer (score 1):

Way late to the game here, but this post still flies high in the Google when searching for similar solutions.

Install the `html2haml` gem, pop into your app/views directory and give this a try:

```
find ./ -name '*.erb' -exec html2haml -e {} {}.haml \;
find ./ -name "*.erb.haml" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.erb.haml}.haml"' _ {} \;
find ./ -name '*.erb' -exec rm {} \;
```

The flaw in this solution is that it doesn't retain revision history from your old .erb files to your new .haml files.  But at times where that revision history of those view files isn't a big deal, this solution has served me pretty well.

Also, be sure to watch for any errors in the html2haml line before you delete the old .erb files.

- [Credit due to this Ask Ubuntu post for the renaming line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35922/how-to-change-extension-of-multiple-files-from-command-line)