# erb to haml conversion to apply body class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have theses two line in erb

```
<body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
<% content_for :body_class, "my_class" %>
```

I have tried

```
- content_for :body_class do
  my_class
```

For above HAML conversion I'm not sure - correct or not !
and not able to figure out HAML conversion for

```
<body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
%body{ class: "#{yield (:body_class)}" }
```

and

```
- content_for :body_class do
    my_class
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `gem` for that!

**`erb2haml`** ([see details on Github](https://github.com/dhl/erb2haml)) .

This gem will give you two commands which will allow you to:

1. convert erb to haml
2. convert and replace erb with haml

To keep the original ERB files you can run:

```
rake haml:convert_erbs
```

To discard the original ERB files after they have been converted to haml you can run:

```
rake haml:replace_erbs
```

There's also a gem called [html2haml](https://github.com/haml/html2haml) which works better if you aren't within a Rails application and/or you only want to convert specific files.

This gem give you the following code after running the html2haml command on your erb file:

```
%body{:class => "#{yield (:body_class)}"}
  - content_for :body_class, "my_class"
```

Comment: Always be careful with this type of thing - like any "translator", it might be correct only 60 / 70% of the time

Comment: Yes it's correct, just saying that when you advocate using a translator, you have to remember to recommend leaning the code etc

Comment: if you can provide some data that proves that this is only correct 60-70% of the time then I'll be quite surprised. Seems that quite a few people agree with me that this gem works quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242699/convert-existing-html-erb-to-haml

Comment: better yet - if you can find a case where it doesn't convert .erb correctly you could create a pull request, write a test, write some code, and fix the edge case in order to improve the gem.